# ANTLR4 DefaultErrorStrategy fails to inject missing token

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to run in TestRig the following grammar:

```
grammar COBOLfragment;

// hidden tokens
WS : [ ]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
NL : '\n' -> channel(HIDDEN);

// keywords
PERIOD : '.';

DIVISION : 'DIVISION';
SECTION : 'SECTION';

DATA : 'DATA';
WORKING_STORAGE : 'WORKING-STORAGE';

FILE : 'FILE';

FD : 'FD';

EXTERNAL : 'EXTERNAL';
GLOBAL : 'GLOBAL';

BLOCK : 'BLOCK';
CONTAINS : 'CONTAINS';
CHARACTERS : 'CHARACTERS';

// data
INTEGER : [0-9]+;
ID : [A-Z][A-Z0-9]*;

dataDivision :
    DATA DIVISION PERIOD
    fileSection?
    workingStorageSection?
;

fileSection :
    FILE SECTION PERIOD
    fileDescription*
;

fileDescription :
    FD fileName=ID
//    (IS? GLOBAL)?          // 1. IS GLOBAL clause
//    (IS? EXTERNAL)?        // 2. IS EXTERNAL clause
    blockClause?
    PERIOD
;

blockClause :
    BLOCK CONTAINS? blockSize=INTEGER CHARACTERS
;

workingStorageSection :
    WORKING_STORAGE SECTION PERIOD
;
```

with the following input:

```
DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.
FD FD01
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
```

Clearly the third line of input ("FD FD01") is missing the terminator `PERIOD` asked for in `fileDescription` rule.

The `DefaultErrorStrategy` correctly acknowledges this and conjures up the missing token:

[image: parse tree with missing token correcly injected]

On stderr the correct report is displayed: `line 4:0 missing '.' at 'WORKING-STORAGE'`.

But if the fragments commented out are enabled (that is, the clauses 'IS EXTERNAL' and 'IS GLOBAL' are brought in the grammar again), then single token insertion fails:

[image: parse tree missing the missing token]

On stderr the misleading report is displayed: `line 4:0 no viable alternative at input 'WORKING-STORAGE'`

**How to enable the full grammar (with IS EXTERNAL and IS GLOBAL clauses) retaining the ability to correct the missing PERIOD?**

Side note 1: if I enable either IS EXTERNAL or IS GLOBAL, but not both clauses, then the `DefaultErrorStrategy` works nicely and injects the missing token.

Side note 2: the code generated for a grammar with both clauses enabled has the following extra code (compared to a grammar with just one of them enabled):

```
public final FileDescriptionContext fileDescription() ... {
    ...
    try {
        ...
        switch ( getInterpreter().adaptivePredict(_input,4,_ctx) ) {
        case 1:
            {
            setState(31);
            _la = _input.LA(1);
            if (_la==IS) {
                {
                setState(30); match(IS);
                }
            }

            setState(33); match(GLOBAL);
            }
            break;
        }
        ...
    }
    catch (RecognitionException re) {
        ...
```

And the `adaptivePredict()` call is the culprit, because it throws `no viable alternative at input 'WORKING-STORAGE'` before the parser has a chance to `match(PERIOD)` (in the generated code, not pasted here).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it adding a new clause for both IS clauses:

(here just the fragments changed)

```
...
fileDescription :
    FD fileName=ID
    isClauses?
    blockClause?
    PERIOD
;

isClauses :
    IS? GLOBAL (IS? EXTERNAL)?
|   IS? EXTERNAL
;
...
```

Now the `DefaultErrorStrategy` does its work and injects the missing `PERIOD`.

**Why not `isClauses : (IS? GLOBAL?) (IS? EXTERNAL)?;`**
Well, I tried that first, of course. But got a warning (warning(154): rule 'fileDescription' contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string) and no missing `PERIOD` injected.